# What is the most robust, extensible way to represent a contract in code?

Tags: language-design, xml, json, dsl

I would like to find or create a syntax to express business contracts programmatically, and I am looking for a robust, flexible, future-resistant way to do this.

A client should be able to add a *negotiation points* of varying types to the contract.

An example of a boolean negotiation point:

- "There is a pre-payment penalty?" (yes/no)

While the above is certainly doable, it seems more difficult to describe the **relationships** between the negotiation points in an abstract way.

### Some examples:

- $600 is paid by "Client A" for inspection.
- The above amount is paid by "Client B" if condition Y (information that should have been disclosed before the inspection was not disclosed).

### Some other possible functionality:

- Virtual fields are calculated based on the numeric values of other fields.

### Notes:

It certainly seems like XML or possibly JSON-schema are possible candidates for describing the above.  But I am open to other options.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_markup_languages

Many thanks,

Comment: You mean a "business contract," right?

Comment: XML and JSON seem like horrible approaches since they don't actually _do_ anything. Contracts need to enforce behavior.

Comment: If you're not afraid to mess with parsing and syntax trees, you could probably make a domain-specific language to represent what you need. That would be the most _extensible_ way of going about it I would think. If that's what you're looking for, look for a programming language that has heavy support for macros and DSLs, such as a flavor of Lisp or Scheme

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, I'm talking about "business contracts".

Comment: @Jack: That sounds like a lot of fun.  Have always wanted to delve deeper into Common Lisp macros.

Comment: @Telastyn: What about json-schema (http://json-schema.org/) and XML schemas?

Comment: @Nathan: I heavily recommend [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) if you wish to go this route. The language has a large toolchain of built in components for building advanced macro systems and entire languages. Common Lisp macros are purely symbol substitutions in nature, which have a few complications associated with them (look up hygienic macros vs. unhygienic macros). Not saying CL is a worse language, just that if you're looking to use a language _primarily_ for its DSL capabilities than you're better off with Racket.

Comment: @nathan - what about them? Defining what your documents contain does not dictate the semantics that they implement.

Comment: @Telastyn: So you're saying that besides having a descriptive format, I need something to translate that format into something more inherently meaningful? Good point, if that is what you are saying.  I would like to translate the descriptive format into user interfaces and English documents.  Of course, these are just ways of describing as well.  FYI I don't plan on building a system that programmatically enforces the contracts themselves.

Comment: @Jack: Just checked Racket out.  I love the intro in pictures :).  Since I am planning on doing this on the web with a reactive UI, it is likely that Racket is not a feasible choice for this.  (unless, possibily, if I use a Racket to JS compiler: https://github.com/dyoo/whalesong).  Thoughts?

Comment: The [Scribble](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/) language built on Racket is specifically designed for constructing written documents while still being a programming language, extending that might be a good idea. As for doing it in the web, you might be able to do it with the document processing running serverside and the UI requesting whatever processing needs to be done asynchronously. Compiling racket to js _might_ work but I have no idea how deep the Whalesong project's support for the things you want to do is.

Comment: @Jack: I really appreciate the response.  I'm going to do some more research into this whole question today, and probably come back with more questions :p.

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly accepted way is to use a [Business Rules Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) of some sort.

Of course, if you're willing to roll your own BRE, and just need a reading on the markup language to use, I would imagine that XML is as good as any.  It is hierarchical, has namespaces, and is unlikely to become obsolete any time soon.  Since it's likely that we're not talking about gigabytes of markup here, the angle bracket tax is unlikely to be a real issue.

Answer (score 2):

At the syntax level, either XML or JSON would do fine. But that's the easy bit. The challenge is defining what can go in the rules. I would adopt a standard object modelling approach: what are the entities you need to represent, and what are their attributes and relationships? When you know that, encoding it in XML is easy.

Comment: Agreed that the challenge is what can go into the rules :).  Have been doing a little of that so far.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is the **huge** set of assumptions that you so easily skip.

Just take your example: "$600 is paid by `Client A` for inspection"

- USD or other dollar?
- Paid when?
- To whom?
- What counts as an inspection?
- Is this a mandatory payment, or only incurred if A opts to do the inspection?
- Are multiple inspections allowed, If so, is this per inspection?

Your DSL will need to deal with all this complexity. For contracts in **English**, lawyers have already developed ways to resolve such issues, and even prevent them by reviewing draft contracts.

Comment: Moreover, they have a defined environment in which conflicts or ambiguities can be resolved, and that serves to enforce the contracts: the court system.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: Good point.  In one of my comments I mentioned that this DSL should be able to be translated into English and a UI.